# AWS CloudFront - Use path path based routing to pull in content from external server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having difficulty mapping a path-based route defined in CloudFront to custom domain. Any ideas what I need to change?

**Background**:
I've got a Vue app that I host on AWS in this way. This all works fine.

- I build and push files to an s3 bucket (www.example.com).
- CloudFront distribution that has an origin set up with that bucket (www.example.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com).
- A CNAME record from www to the Cloudfront domain name (d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net)

Now I want content from a separate domain on a separate server to show up as a path on the domain rather than a subdomain like it is now. I have a blog at blog.example.com that I would like to see as www.example.com/blog.

I went through these steps:

1. Add new custom origin to the Cloudfront distribution (blog.example.com)
2. Add a new behavior to Cloudfront distribution with path pattern="blog" and Origin set to the one above ("Custom-blog.example.com")
3. Set the new behavior as priority 0 and the default (*) to priority 1

https://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/blog does a redirect to https://blog.example.com

but https://www.example.com/blog does not

Any ideas?

Here the config images:

Origin:

[image]

---

Behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set "Origin Protocol Policy" to "HTTPS Only". Otherwise, Cloudfront is talking plain HTTP with the origin, which may produces unwanted redirects.

After that, invalidate the desired path fragments, since redirects can be cached as well.

Comment: It may takes up to 30 min until the change (and the invalidation!) takes affect...

Comment: Thanks Joe. I did a full invalidation across the whole distribution and waited an hour :(

Comment: hi @scim, did you manage to get this working ? I have a similar requirement and was wondering if you can share a reference you used for this ? Thanks!

Comment: @Illuminati no unfortunately not. I had to setup a process to copy static content to the bucket, which is sub-optimal.

Comment: turns out I manage to get that setup easily. let me know what issues you have if you'd still like to get it resolved.